# add highes as a column using Window Functions

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have a table like below:

[image: Pic1]

Query to replicate data:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS units_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE units_table
(
 Brand varchar(100),
 units numeric(38,12)
);


  INSERT INTO units_table (Brand, units)
   VALUES ('A',200),('B',0),('C',300),('D',400),('E',1500),('F',700),('G',800),('H',450);
```

Using window functions specifically, I want to get the highest against the table. Like below:

[image: P2]

However when I use:

```
select

brand,
units,
FIRST_VALUE(units) OVER () as Highest

from units_table
```

Its gives the first value as 0. if I do,

```
select

brand,
units,
FIRST_VALUE(units) OVER (ORDER BY UNITS) as Highest

from units_table
```

Throws an error.
How should I use Window Function specifically to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems that you did not post your actual code because your 2nd query runs without any error: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ojpcT2nj2echrePMLUyWV/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT brand,
       units,
       MAX(units) OVER () AS Highest
FROM units_table;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74d8b15f5f4154e636d2c285253d10c8).

Comment: Works! Thank you, any idea why order by isnt working?

Comment: @user2458552 check the link in my comment under your question. It works without any error, although you need to add DESC in the ORDER BY clause. Can you reproduce the error that you get in my fiddle? But to get the max value the proper way to do it is with MAX() window function.

Comment: Ok thanks, found the reason I am using AWS redshift database for the SQL query, the order by clause isn't running because of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select brand,units,
 FIRST_VALUE(units) OVER (ORDER BY UNITS DESC) as Highest
from units_table
```

works for me

Comment: Doesnt work for me :(. It says syntax error.

Comment: perhaps your mysql does not support this syntax